# Displaying data from div to another div

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react

Im creating a simple image card that once clicked, a modal will show.

```
    state = {
      test_people: [
        {
           name: 'John Doe',
           occupation: 'Full Stack Developer',
           details: 'Lorem ipsum..'
        },
        {
           name: 'Mary Jane',
           occupation: 'Front-End Developer',
           details: 'Lorem ipsum..'
        },
        {
           name: 'James Green',
           occupation: 'Back-End Developer',
           details: 'Lorem ipsum..'
        },
      ]
    },

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    }

    showPop(key) {
      let people_details = document.getElementsByClassName('')[key];
    }

    render() {

      const test_people = [...this.state.test_people];

      // image card
      <div className="container">
        {
          test_people.map( ( tp, i ) =>
            <div className="card_people" onClick={ () => this.showPop(i) } key={ i }>
            <p>{ tp.name }</p>

            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>

      // for modal
      <div className="container">
        // other person details will show here
      </div>
    }
```

I want to pass array to another div, is it possible? Once I clicked the name a modal will pop out and show other details.

Any suggestions guys? it will be appreciated

Comment: is you modal another component? If yes, you could pass that array to the modal component like <ModalComponent data={arrayData} />

Comment: No @Ange, its just another div but im having trouble how to pass data on it and how to trigger it.

Comment: If that's the case you don't have to pass the array to the div since they are just one big component. Also is the code above your actual code? If that's the case I think you will get a lot of errors (i.e. not having a return statement; rendering two div elements in one component etc)

Comment: you can generate that array before return then use as many times you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach 
// backdrop css

```
 .Backdrop {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

//ModalContent Component

```
const ModalContent = (props)=>{
        return (
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
             {/*   <h3 style={{color: '#008000'}}>Success</h3>*/}
                <b><h2 style={{color: '#008000'}}>{props.title}</h2></b>
                <h4 style={{color: '#008000'}}>{props.details}</h4>
            </div>
        )}
```

//Modal Component

```
   const Modal = ( props ) => (
                <Aux>
                    <Backdrop show={props.show} clicked={(e)=>props.modalClosed(false)} />
                    <div
                        className={"Modal"}
                        style={{
                            transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                            opacity: props.show ? '1' : '0'
                        }}>
                        {props.children}
                    </div>
                </Aux>
            );
```

// code

```
    constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                test_people: [
                    {
                        name: 'John Doe',
                        occupation: 'Full Stack Developer',
                        details: 'Lorem ipsum..'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Mary Jane',
                        occupation: 'Front-End Developer',
                        details: 'Lorem ipsum..'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'James Green',
                        occupation: 'Back-End Developer',
                        details: 'Lorem ipsum..'
                    },
                ],
                modal: false
            }
            this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
        }
         modalHandler = (props)=> {
            this.setState((state)=>({
                modal: props
            }));
        };
        showPop = (key)=> {
            let people_details = document.getElementsByClassName('')[key];
        }
        render() {
            const test_people = [...this.state.test_people];
            let array =   test_people.map( ( tp, i ) => {
                return <div className="card_people" onClick={() => this.showPop(i)} key={i}>
                    <p>{tp.name}</p>
                </div>
            }
        )
            // image card
            return(
                <React.fragment>
                <div className="container">   {array}  </div>
                 //for modal
<Modal show={this.state.modal} modalClosed={this.modalHandler}>
                                    <ModalContent
                                        status={this.state.axiosStatus.status}
                                        title={this.state.axiosStatus.title}
                                        details= 
 {this.state.axiosStatus.details}
                                    />
                                </Modal>
                <div className="container">
                // other person details will show here
                    {array}
                </div>
                </React.fragment>
        )}
```

Comment: Hi @anik, how to trigger image card? once clicked that modal div will appear?